# When invoke Java Sparkcontext constructor my Maven web app stops without exceptions or other messages

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, ejb, glassfish-4

i have a problem with Maven WebApp with following dependences :

```
   ` <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>`
```

In a EJB (@stateless with local interface, called from a servlet) i have :

```
 public void callSpark(QParams qp){
   String uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/admin.EventCollection";
   try {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("local")
            .setAppName("BigDataEvent")
            .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitioner", 
                    "MongoPaginateBySizePartitioner")
            .set("spark.app.id", "BigDataAnalysis")
            .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri)
            .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", uri);
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf); 
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
    SQLContext sqlc = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(jsc);
    Dataset<Row> df = MongoSpark.load(jsc).toDF();
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("EventCollection");
    postCodeQuery(df,qp); //my method
    eventTypeQuery(sparkSession, eventType); //my method
   } catch (Exception ex){Logger.getLogger(SparkContext.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

This code works very well in a Java Client Maven application but in this situation (Maven Web APP) the application crashes (without exception and error message) when I call :

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

The application make build and deploy (on GlassFish 4.1.1) without errors or exception.
Anyone Had Similar Experiences with this configuration?
Thanks...